# maven-scala-plugin stuck on readInt scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, maven-scala-plugin

I have scala application, and having pom.xml that uses maven scala plugin, My application uses scala `readInt` to read an Integer from the Command Line

The project is build on eclipse, when i run the scala application using eclipse it works

when i try to use scala plugin to run the same application it stucks readInt

```
mvn scala:run  -DmainClass=run.readFromConsole
```

did i missing anything ?

This is the exception trace

```
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException: Console has reached end of input
    at scala.Console$.readInt(Console.scala:349)
    at scala.Predef$.readInt(Predef.scala:296)
    at run.readFromConsole$$anonfun$1.apply$mcVI$sp(readFromConsole.scala:6)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at run.readFromConsole$delayedInit$body.apply(readFromConsole.scala:5)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at run.readFromConsole$.main(readFromConsole.scala:3)
    at run.readFromConsole.main(readFromConsole.scala)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.929s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 03 16:42:20 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/299M
```

the code

```
object readFromConsole extends App {

  for (i <- 0 to 4) {
      println("Console Input " +i+ " "  + readInt )
  }

}
```

The code runs fine with standalone, using scalac,scala or even from eclipse scala application, when i try to run from the mvn scala application  it throws the error.

```
mvn clean compile scala:run  -DmainClass=run.readFromConsole
```

Comment: Sooo, you're giving it int, right?

Comment: don't get your last comment at all